# Does the Fourier transform have an infinite number of eigenvalues?

Tags: fourier-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to prove or disprove that the Fourier transform has an infinite number of eigenvalues. I am unable to proceed.

Comment: As I recall the eigenvalues of the Fourier transform are precisely $1,-1,i,-i$. So I don't think this is right.

Comment: Can you please give me link where I'll find the proof.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad: See here for a proof, including some explicitly calculated eigenfunctions for each eigenvalue. https://www2.bc.edu/~reederma/FourierEvecs.pdf

Answer (score 5):

There are several spaces on which the Fourier transform is an operator $\mathcal{F} : X \to X$. For example, $X$ can be the Schwartz space or $L^2$. In both of those cases, we have $\mathcal{F}^4 = I$, the identity operator. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then we must have $\mathcal{F}x = \lambda x$ for some nonzero $x \in X$. Applying $\mathcal{F}$ three more times, we get
$$x = Ix = \mathcal{F}^4 x = \lambda^4 x$$
This forces $\lambda^4 = 1$, so as mentioned in the comment by @Ian, the eigenvalues are $1, -1, i, -i$, at least on these spaces. I'm not sure if this generalizes to other spaces on which $\mathcal{F}$ is an operator, for example the space of tempered distributions.